# android studio 3.3 not showing action bar and status bar in its preview window after creating new project

Tags: android, android-studio-3.3

android studio 3.3 not showing action bar and status bar in its preview window after creating new project.i already tried this in build.graadle(module:app) file (implementation'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1')

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the preview tab, click on the eye and select 'Show Layout Decorations'.

[image]

**EDIT:** Toolbar isn't showing because of my style settings - I used 'NoActionBar'. This should work for you, though.

Comment: Thanks.it solved the problem.i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Try this on your styles.xml