# preview not working after update Android Studio to version 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm not seeing action bar after updating android  to version 3.3 , So this is a bug or the option is disabled. please help.

[image]

Comment: add your code trials and error messages you getting

Comment: @ Dev -  no exist error in my codes but don't show default action bar in preview

Comment: Follow this step. May solve your issue.

01. Goto File and Sync project with gradle files.
02. Goto File and Invalid caches and restart.

Comment: @ Masum --- so i should to clear cache gradle file  and i  sync again ..

Comment: yes. you can do it. Maybe solved.

Comment: @ Masum ---   ok i do , if my issues solved, i am say

Comment: don't work for me after than clear cache android gradle

Comment: finally i don't found way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this Answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54240003/566127

Check that "Show Layout Decorations" is enabled in your preview pane:

[image]

Comment: thanks dear friend ...

Answer (score 1):

Go to styles.xml and add Base before Theme.AppCompat. Means it should then look like-

```
 Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

And go to Built and select "clean project" or "Rebuild project".
If it doesn't work then choose option "Invalidate Caches/Restart" under file menu.
(Sometimes choosing only this works well without changing in xml)

Try it, I hope it will also work for you.

Comment: dear friend .don't worke me ,this way